# Prop up tablet computer angling display downwards

Tags: technology, comfort

I like watching videos on my tablet computer while lying down on my sofa. In order to see the display without being forced to watch sideways or getting a kink in my neck, I have to hold the tablet in my hand above my body. Since this gets too heavy very quickly, I thought about propping the tablet up on the back rest of my sofa.

My problem is that any stand or prop always has the display facing upwards. But my head lies below the tablet, so I'd like it to face downwards (without covering too much of the display).

**How can I mount my tablet onto the backrest or a big pillow of my sofa so the display faces down?**

I need to use my tablet for other purposes than watching videos, so the solution should not permanently attach it to the sofa or otherwise make it hard to use. It's acceptable to buy and repurpose appliances and other stuff for this, as long as I can store the result away when it's not needed.

Comment: Are you lying down across the sofa, looking at the tablet by turning your head sideways, or ‘sitting’ slouched into the sofa and looking at the tablet by lifting your head up? I thought it was the first, but you said you didn’t want to tilt your head sideways.

Comment: Yes, I'm lying down across the sofa, head on the armrest. But I don't want to look at the tablet sideways, I'd like to have it in front of my face. Usually I cram my hand into the tablet cover as best as possible, then prop my arm on my chest to use it as a surrogate stand, but that's heavy, uncomfortable and causing me cramps in my hand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can find or fashion a cross-bar above your head, hang the tablet by a couple of heavy elastic bands or bungee cord in a position most comfortable for viewing. The position of your tablet can be adjusted for most any angle from horizontally facing downward to nearly vertical. It's easy to slide the tablet onto and off the cross-bar. Maybe you can wedge the upright between the cushions for a sturdy mount. Let your vivid imagination run wild.

[image: hanging tablet set-up]

The materials are cheap and the cross-bar doesn't need to support much weight. If possible, construct the assembly so that it can swivel out of your way so you can get up and lie down again without hassles.

Another benefit of this rig is that the tablet can remain attached to the power adapter for binge viewing.

Have fun and good luck with your project.

EDIT: I was thinking about the support and I suggest visiting your local hardware store to get some stiff plastic tubing, an elbow and a "wye" connector, and caps if you want to have a finished look for the support. Assemble the parts as shown and put the base under the couch cushion you're lying on.

[image: Adjustable position tablet-holder stand]

Answer (score 1):

Years ago, I had a friend that liked to watch TV in bed lying down without lifting his head.  He got a pair of glasses that redirected his vision 90 degrees (see link below).  If you get a pair of those, you can rest your tablet on a regular stand on your belly but it will appear to be above your head.

Lazy Readers Prism Glasses Bed Prism Spectacles Horizontal Eyeglasses for Reading/Watching TV Lying Down in Bed/Sofa, Myopia Presbyopic usable, Unisex [https://www.amazon.com/dp/B079M2NZV4/ref=cm_sw_r_cp_apa_i_WWRHCb07CTG6W](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B079M2NZV4)

Comment: Just so you know, there are high-quality versions of this product, and low-quality versions. I bought an inexpensive pair on Amazon and had a hard time seeing with them. I can't remember what the issue was, but it could have been a lot of things:  the mirrors aren't quite angled the right way, or the mirrors are slightly imperfect (wavy), or the mirroring on the back of the mirrors isn't quit perfect, or there's a slight tiny smudge on one of the mirrors. Paying more will probably get you higher-quality glasses.

Answer (score 0):

Use a cook book support. You can find plenty of them on Amazon or E-bay.

Comment: Hi Zana. Thank you for your answer, but can you please explain how these supports work and how they would solve my problem? On StackExchange we encourage self-contained answers that have all the necessary information. Have a look at the [tour] and the [help] to read more about it. The more information your answers contain (the more helpful they are), the higher are the chances of getting upvotes.

Comment: IThis is what I had in mind: a book support like this https://www.amazon.com/Wedo-Bamboo-Book-Stand-Brown/dp/B0039FCUG0?ref_=Oct_UPriceC_678506011_4&pf_rd_r=3C6CY0GJCT11A94GFC95&pf_rd_p=880ee2e4-5624-5c0e-93bc-59cfdec78f93&pf_rd_s=merchandised-search-10&pf_rd_t=101&pf_rd_i=678506011&pf_rd_m=ATVPDKIKX0DER Just place it in your lap while lying on your sofa and select the best angle.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up buying a very cheap shoe rack made of some aluminum pipes and plastic connectors, like this example:

[image]

By removing the lowest layer from the example, you get legs that should be high enough to lay underneath for most people. You can adjust the height by adding or removing layers.

My tablet has a flap at the back that acts as an integrated stand and I fasten it to the horizontal pipes with 2 plastic spring clamps. The only disadvantage is that the construction isn't sturdy and certainly not designed to be moved around a lot. My shoe rack fell apart several times and I had to reessemble it, but that's no big effort.